# merging dictionary and Counter object

Tags: python-3.x

Bellow is code where I am trying to merge Dictionary with category with default zero value, with Counter object with two or more dictionary with category from Dictionary however, not all exist in it. Result will give one list with two or more dictionary depends of number of dictionary in Counter object. If Dictionary key is equal to first counter object dictionary key, then value will be replaced and so on.

```
Result = []
        for data in CounterList:
            for kd, vd in Dictionary:

                for kc, vc in data.items():
                    if kd == kc:
                        Dictionary.update({key: valueIn})

                Result.append(Dictionary)
        print("Result", Result)
```

### Counter List:

`[Counter({'A': 10, 'B': 15, 'C': 5,'E': 8}), Counter({'A': 15, 'D': 5, 'F': 20,'G': 20})]`

### Dictionary:

`{'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0,'E':0,'F':0,'G':0}`

### Result:

`[{'A':10,'B':15,'C':5,'D':0,'E':8,'F':0,'G':0},{'A':15,'B':0,'C':0,'D':5,'E':0,'F':20,'G':20}]`

Comment: Please share the code by editing question so we can help you.

Comment: Ok, but do you have a problem/question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop over your counter-objects, and some deep-copying of your template result thingy:

```
from collections import Counter
import copy

counts = [Counter({'A': 10, 'B': 15, 'C': 5,'E': 8}), 
          Counter({'A': 15, 'D': 5, 'F': 20,'G': 20})]

d_template = {'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0,'E':0,'F':0,'G':0} 

result = []

for c in counts:
    # deep copy your template 
    result.append(copy.deepcopy(d_template))
    # and update it to the current counter data
    result[-1].update(c)


print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 10, 'B': 15, 'C': 5, 'D': 0, 'E': 8, 'F': 0,  'G': 0}, 
 {'A': 15, 'B': 0,  'C': 0, 'D': 5, 'E': 0, 'F': 20, 'G': 20}]
```